always focused and top windows in WFA C#
I have a windows form app which has only 1 form with a Textbox. I want my app always on top and focused in that Textbox. I do several things and they worked on some of the computers but there are a few which, when I restart or turn on the pc my app starts automatically but not focused in. I have a timer which continually make the form active and focused.
My client pc's run windows 10.
        private void timer_focus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Activate();
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Focus();
    }


What if two programs did this?.

thank you very much for the article you send. since there isn't any other app on the windows, I try to focus on the textbox instead of form and for now I solve the problem.

This looks like XY problem. Explain what is X, maybe there is a better solution, because what you ask is pretty harmful to the user. I would NOT expect any software to constantly deactivate other windows and steal focus.

My app should run in a specific area which there is no need for user interacts. It just collect the data which comes from barcode scanners and insert it to DB. I want it to be on top and focused because there is no mouse and keyboards for users to do anything else. So if I lose the focus I have to carry a mouse or keyboard to fix the problem.
